# Is this converting from or to premultiplied alpha?

Tags: c#, color

I found this code buried under some rocks:

```
var divAlpha = 0xff00/color.A;
var r = (byte) (color.R*divAlpha >> 8);
var g = (byte) (color.G*divAlpha >> 8);
var b = (byte) (color.B*divAlpha >> 8);
```

The fields on `color` are bytes, of course. My guess would be it's avoiding using floating point operations to handle premultiplied alpha, but is it converting *from* or *to*? How does this work out?

Example output:

```
0x44112233 -> a: 0x44, r: 0x3f, g: 0x7f, b: 0xbf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is converting *from* premultiplied alpha:

Expanding one of the assignments by substituting for ***divAlpha***:

```
var r = (byte) (color.R*(0xff00/color.A) >> 8);
```

which on rearrangement of the multiplicative terms becomes

```
var r = (byte) ((color.R*(0xff00) >> 8)/color.A);
```

which in turn simplifies to:

```
var r = (byte) (color.R*0xff /color.A);
```

or

```
var r = (byte) (color.R * (0xff /color.A) );
```

which is clearly seen to be a division by the (fractional) alpha channel value.

This can be verified by computing the reverse operation:

```
R: (0x3F * 0x44 + 0x80) >> 8 = 0x113C >> 8 = 0x11
G: (0x7F * 0x44 + 0x80) >> 8 = 0x223C >> 8 = 0x22
B: (0xBF * 0x44 + 0x80) >> 8 = 0x333C >> 8 = 0x33
```

Comment: Note that to avoid precision loss, and properly take advantage of the structure discovered by OP, the original operation should probably be: `var r = (byte) ( (color.R*divAlpha + 0x80) >> 8);`